# Loading nested gridview with jquery for very large data

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net

I am trying to load the nested gridview with jquery but i don't want to reload the data if its already loaded by the user. because retrieving detail data is big and time costly.

Scenario: Consider country and cities scenario. cities will be loaded with jquery. 
I dont want to load the cities name if cities name already loaded.

I tried to manage not to load data everytime with checking detail row with data exist or not.

However i cant able to expand and collapse the detail row. Please have a look at my javascript

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $('.view').click(function () {
        var expand = $(this).attr("src"); // image like + and - to expand and collapse
        if (expand.includes("plus.png")) { // load details
            $(this).attr("src", "../images/minus.png");
            var ID = $(this).attr("data-id");
            if ($(this).closest('tr').next('tr').attr("id") != "bookings") { // checking if detail data TR already exist or not
                $(this).closest('tr').after('<tr id="bookings"><td colspan="100%" style="padding: 5px;"></td></tr>');
                $('#bookings td').load('conferenceBookerBookingList.aspx?conferenceBooker=' + ID + ' #bookingList');
            } else {
                $(this).closest('tr').next('tr').style.display = "block";
            }
        } else { // hide or collpase the detail row
            $(this).attr("src", "../images/plus.png");
            $('#bookings').remove(); // this will be remove if i manage to hide and show the detail row
            //if ($(this).closest('tr').next('tr').attr("id") != "bookings") {

            //}
        }
        return false;
    });
</script>
```

Thanks

Comment: is the - and + even work? I'm asking because "includes" is use for array, not strings. Have you tried "expand == 'plus.png'" instead? btw, use .on(click,function() instead of .click(function() to get a live fresh action each time

Comment: Hi - and + event works. I can use the compare operator it not a problem.

Comment: Ok fine. But because it works doesn't mean it's not a problem, don't use includes to test something as trivial as a string. Just an advice :)

Comment: Have you tried the live version of the click btw?

Comment: check this article here https://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/ASPNet-Nested-GridViews-GridView-inside-GridView-with-Expand-and-Collapse-feature.aspx

Comment: I change my code   $('.view').live("click",function () { it through the error "Uncaught TypeError: $(...).live is not a function"

Comment: link you refer he is binding nested gridview when master row bind. However my problem is i am loading content on demand.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my final script. Some of the customer have "&" character in their name. Javascript encodeURI method did not encode "&" character. So my server side code things there are more query string parameter. I solved by manually replace & character with %26.

```
                <script type="text/javascript">
                $('.view').on("click", function () {
                    var expand = $(this).attr("src");
                    var tr = $(this).closest("tr");
                    if (expand == "../images/expand.png") {                            
                        if (tr.next().find("table").length == 1) {
                            $(this).attr("src", "../images/collapse.png");
                            tr.next().show();
                            return;
                        }
                        tr.after("<tr id='bookings'><td colspan='100%' style='padding: 10px;'><img src='../images/Vanta.gif' align='middle'/> <span style='verticla-align: middle; padding-left: 5px; color: red; font-weight: bold;'> Please be patient, the data is loading</span></td></tr>");
                        var url = encodeURI("conferenceBooker=" + $(this).attr("data-id").replace("&", "%26") + "&startDate=" + $('.startDate').val() + "&endDate=" + $('.endDate').val() + "&venue=" + $('.venue').val());
                        $.get("test.aspx", url, function (data, status) {
                            if (status == "success") {
                                var resp = "<tr id='bookings'><td colspan='100%' style='padding: 10px;'>" + data + "</td></tr>";
                                tr.next().remove();
                                tr.after(resp);
                            }
                            if (status == "error") {
                                tr.next().remove();
                                tr.after("<tr id='bookings'><td colspan='100%' style='padding: 10px;'>Error occure during loading data</td></tr>");
                            }
                        });
                        $(this).attr("src", "../images/collapse.png");
                    } else {
                        $(this).attr("src", "../images/expand.png");
                        if (tr.next().find("table").length == 1) {
                            tr.next().hide();
                        }
                    }
                    return false;
                });
            </script>
```